# Как получить FXML объект JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

хочу получить FXML объект, но получаю null.
В то же время, если передавать ссылку в аргумент в метод, то ссылка валидна.

```
import controller.MainController;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;

public class MenuButtonEvent {
static MainController mc = new MainController();

public static void setText(MenuButton mb) {
    MenuButton m = mc.getMenuButton(); 
    System.out.print(m);  //null
    System.out.print(mb); // MenuButton[id=menuButton, styleClass=menu-button]'3x3'


    }
}
```

MainController:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private MenuButton menuButton;

    @FXML
    public MenuButton getMenuButton() {
        return menuButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Погуглите `FXMLLoader`. И советую почитать про то как работает `JavaFX` в целом.

Answer (score 0):

А у вас есть файл fxml?

Если нет, то вот вам код, который должен работать т.к вы хотите

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")); 
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);

       stage.setScene(scene);

       stage.setTitle("Пример");
       stage.setWidth(250);
       stage.setHeight(200);

       stage.show();
   }
}
```

Main.fxml

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<Group fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
<MenuButton <!-- свойства кнопки --> onAction="#click" />
</Group>
```

MainController.java

```
 public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private MenuButton btn;

    @FXML
    private void click(ActionEvent event) {
        //делайте что то со своей кнопкой
    }
}
```